# How does the standard deviation change if you change one value?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Question: There are 23 employees in a particular division of a company. Their salaries have a mean of \$70,000, a median of \$55,000, and a standard deviation of \$20,000. The largest number on the list is \$100,000. By accident, this number is changed to \$1,000,000.

I am asked to calculate the new standard deviation, which is
$$
\sqrt{ \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\bar{x})^{2}}{n-1} }
$$

where $\bar{x}$ is the new mean, which is
$$
\frac{23\cdot 70,000-100,000+1,000,000}{23}=109,130.43
$$

Plugging in $\bar{x}$, I need to calculate
$$
\sqrt{ \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-109,130.43)^{2}}{22} }
$$

Here's where I'm having trouble. How can I calculate the new standard deviation without knowing each $x_{i}$?

It doesn't seem to help that I know the old standard deviation is
$$
\sqrt{ \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-70,000)^{2}}{22} }=20,000
$$
since I don't think the new standard deviation can be rewritten to include this expression.

Comment: Probably as good an example as any to demonstrate why removing extreme values prior to computing sample statistics can be a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen the solution and understood it. The equality $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\bar{x})^{2}=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}-n\bar{x}^{2}$, credit to Andrei for pointing it out, seems to simplify things significantly.

**Note: all numbers will be in thousands.**

##### For the original set of $n=23$ numbers containing 100:

For convenience, we define the following
$$T_{0}=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}$$

Let $\bar{x}_{0}=70,V_{0},S_{0}$ be the mean, variance, standard deviation. We have
$$
V_{0}=S_{0}^{2}=400=\frac{1}{n-1}(T_{0}-n\bar{x}_{0}^{2})
$$
We get $T_{0}=121,500$ after solving for it.

##### For the changed set of $n=23$ numbers containing 1000:

$$T_{1}=T_{0}-100^{2}+1000^{2}=1,111,500$$
Let $\bar{x}_{1}=109.13043,V_{1},S_{1}$ be the new mean, variance, and standard deviation
$$\displaylines{
V_{1}=S_{1}^{2}=\frac{1}{n-1}(T_{1}-n\bar{x}_{1}^{2})
}$$
After solving, we get that $S_{1}=195.12$ and we are done.

The new standard deviation is \$195,120.

Comment: Congratulations. Good job

Answer (score 1):

Start from $$\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i^2-2x_i\bar x+(\bar x)^2)\\=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-n(\bar x)^2$$
Proceed the same way as for mean. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}, x_n)$ be the correct data, and let $(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}, x_n')$ be the incorrect data, so $x_n' \ne x_n$.

The sample mean of each data set is
$$\bar x = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i, \quad \bar x' = \frac{1}{n} \left(x_n' + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i \right). \tag{1}$$
So $$\bar x - \bar x' = \frac{1}{n} (x_n - x_n') \tag{2}$$ which allows us to calculate the correct sample mean from the incorrect sample mean.

The correct and incorrect sample variances are respectively
$$s = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2, \quad s' = \frac{1}{n-1} \left( (x_n' - \bar x')^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (x_i - \bar x')^2 \right). \tag{3}$$
We want to write the correct variance in terms of the incorrect one, so this suggests writing
$$\begin{align}
s &= \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x' + \bar x' - \bar x)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x')^2 + 2(x_i - \bar x')(\bar x' - \bar x) + (\bar x' - \bar x)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{n-1} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x')^2 + 2(\bar x' - \bar x)\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x') + n(\bar x' - \bar x)^2 \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n-1} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x')^2 + 2(\bar x' - \bar x)(n \bar x - n \bar x') + n(\bar x' - \bar x)^2 \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n-1} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x')^2 - n(\bar x' - \bar x)^2 \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n-1} \left( (x_n' - \bar x')^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (x_i - \bar x')^2 + (x_n - \bar x')^2 - (x_n' - \bar x')^2 - n(\bar x' - \bar x)^2 \right) \\
&= s' + \frac{(x_n - \bar x')^2 - (x_n' - \bar x')^2 - n(\bar x' - \bar x)^2}{n-1} \\
&= s' + \frac{(x_n - \bar x' + x_n' - \bar x')(x_n - \bar x' - x_n' + \bar x') - n(\bar x' - \bar x)^2}{n-1} \\
&= s' + \frac{(x_n + x_n' - 2\bar x')(x_n - x_n') - (x_n - x_n')^2/n}{n-1} \\
&= s' + \frac{x_n - x_n'}{n-1} \left( x_n + x_n' - 2\bar x' - \frac{x_n - x_n'}{n} \right) \\
&= s' + \frac{x_n - x_n'}{n-1} \left( \frac{n-1}{n} x_n + \frac{n+1}{n} x_n' - \bar x' + \frac{x_n - x_n'}{n} - \bar x \right) \\
&= s' + \frac{x_n - x_n'}{n-1}(x_n + x_n' - (\bar x + \bar x')). \tag{4}
\end{align}$$

---

To apply this result, suppose $n = 7$, the incorrect value is $x_7' = 10$, the incorrect mean is $\bar x' = 15$, and the incorrect variance is $s' = 19$.  The correct value is $x_7 = 5$.  Then the correct mean is
$$\bar x = 15 + \frac{1}{7}(5 - 10) = \frac{100}{7},$$
and the correct variance is
$$s = 19 + \frac{5 - 10}{7 - 1}\left(5 + 10 - (\tfrac{100}{7} + 15)\right) = \frac{649}{21}.$$

Comment: By changing the incorrect value from 10 to 5, the incorrect variance goes from 19 to around 30.9. Are you sure?

Comment: @RyanWang Well, the mean was originally $15$, and so the change of one observation from $10$ to $5$ should increase the dispersion of the data.  You can test the formula $(4)$ by creating a data set, say $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)$.  Calculate the sample mean and variance.  Then replace one observation with another value, say $1$ becomes $10$.  Recalculate the sample mean and variance.  Then use the formula $(4)$ to calculate the sample variance.  It should match.